# Grouping list item using with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following simple list item code in my html file

```
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item three</li>

    <li>item four</li>
    <li>item five</li>
    <li>item six</li>

    <li>item seven</li>
    <li>item eight</li>
    <li>item nine</li>

    <li>item ten</li>
    <li>item eleven</li>
    <li>item twelve</li>    
</ul>
```

and i want to output like this way using with jQuery.

```
item one     item four    item seven    item ten
item two     item five    item eight    item eleven
item three   item six     item nine     item twelve
```

Comment: Are they always to be split by threes, or is there some other algorithm?  Do you care if the HTML gets changed?

Comment: Fixed it :-) .... -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey4WL/1/) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that creates multiple `UL` and floats them

CSS

```
.col_4 {
    width:25%;
    float:left
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list"><li></li></ul>
```

JS

```
/* config*/
var numCols = 4,
    listClass = 'list';

var $list = $('.' + listClass),
    $container = $list.parent(),
    $items = $list.children().detach(),
    numItems = $items.length,
    itemsPerCol = Math.ceil(numItems / numCols),
    sliceStart = 0;

/* remove original empty list and create new ones*/
$list.remove();

for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    var endSlice = sliceStart + itemsPerCol + 1;
    $('<ul class="' + listClass + ' col_' + numCols + '">')
                        .append($items.slice(sliceStart, endSlice))
                        .appendTo($container);
    sliceStart += itemsPerCol;
};
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/G7BfY/